# when does a function will include stack _Unwind_Resume call in c++?

Tags: c++, exception, gcc

I am now studying c++ exception and a trouble comes to me, program show as below

```
#include<iostream>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<string>
#include<thread>
#include<vector>
#include<exception>
using namespace std;


vector<int> vec(20);


void fn()throw() {
        vec.at(10);
}

int main(){
        fn();

return 0;
}
```

I use gdb to disassemble **fn()**, and we can see **callq  0x4008d0 _Unwind_Resume@plt**, it is a call to stack unwind operation since vector::at might throw an out of range exception

```
Dump of assembler code for function fn():
   0x00000000004009e6 <+0>:     push   %rbp
   0x00000000004009e7 <+1>:     mov    %rsp,%rbp
   0x00000000004009ea <+4>:     mov    $0xa,%esi
   0x00000000004009ef <+9>:     mov    $0x6020a0,%edi
   0x00000000004009f4 <+14>:    callq  0x400ba6 <std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >::at(unsigned long)>
   0x00000000004009f9 <+19>:    jmp    0x400a11 <fn()+43>
   0x00000000004009fb <+21>:    cmp    $0xffffffffffffffff,%rdx
   0x00000000004009ff <+25>:    je     0x400a09 <fn()+35>
   0x0000000000400a01 <+27>:    mov    %rax,%rdi
   0x0000000000400a04 <+30>:    callq  0x4008d0 <_Unwind_Resume@plt>
   0x0000000000400a09 <+35>:    mov    %rax,%rdi
   0x0000000000400a0c <+38>:    callq  0x400880 <__cxa_call_unexpected@plt>
   0x0000000000400a11 <+43>:    pop    %rbp
   0x0000000000400a12 <+44>:    retq   
End of assembler dump.
```

however, when I try to imitate this progress with calling a function will throw exception , assembler code **call <_Unwind_Resume>**  doesn't exist,why?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<string>
#include<thread>
#include<vector>
#include<exception>
using namespace std;


class myException:public exception  
{  
        public:  
                myException(){ } 
};


void fn()throw() {
        throw myException();
}

void fn2()throw(){
        fn();
}


int main(){
        fn2();

        return 0;
}
```

assembler code for function fn2(), it doesn't include **call Unwind_Resume@plt**,why?

```
(gdb) disassemble fn2
Dump of assembler code for function fn2():
   0x0000000000400aec <+0>:     push   %rbp
   0x0000000000400aed <+1>:     mov    %rsp,%rbp
   0x0000000000400af0 <+4>:     callq  0x400aa6 <fn()>
   0x0000000000400af5 <+9>:     nop
   0x0000000000400af6 <+10>:    pop    %rbp
   0x0000000000400af7 <+11>:    retq   
End of assembler dump.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since `fn2` only calls `fn`, which is declared as [`throw()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/except_spec), no exception can propagate to an active stack frame for `fn`. GCC recognizes this situation and optimizes the exception handler away.

In the original case, this is not possible because `std::vector::at(size_type)` can throw. The exception handler is only needed because of the `throw()` declaration, to call [`std::unexpected()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/unexpected) in case of an exception.

`_Unwind_Resume` only shows up if the stack frame needs some special action when unwinding (such as calling destructors or `std::unexpected()`). Without that, the Itanium C++ ABI (which is used by GCC) does not require any per-frame action at all, which is why this implementation is sometimes called *zero-cost exception handling*.

Comment: many thanks, I mistake that `throw()` will throw all exceptions to the outside but it actually  depends on type in brackets, `throw()` means throwing nothing, thing go to ok after replaced with `throw(myException)` . However, another question comes, it  seems that `throw()` is deprecated and recomment `noexcept()` , so I use `noexcept(false)` to replace `throw(myException)`, then  `call Unwind_Resume@plt` of `fn()`'s assembler code disappears, so I really want to figure out that does the `call Unwind_Resume@plt`  is executed by caller to resume those stacks of called functions, right?